# ramda has typescript error when using filter

Tags: typescript, ramda.js

I want to use ramda in my typescript project but I am a little bit confused about the usage.

Ramda is complaining about `filter` within a `pipe` with an error I do not understand.

Here is my reduced sample:

```
import * as R from 'ramda';

// Dummy types for Stackoverflow
export enum EventLabel {
  started = 'started',
  answered = 'answered',
  checked = 'checked',
}
type TimestampedEventType = {
  label: EventLabel;
  timestamp: number;
};

export interface Timerange {
  start?: number;
  end?: number;
  durationInMillis?: number;
}

type TimerangeReduceResult = { result: Timerange[]; current?: Timerange };

export const findStartEndPairs = (events: TimestampedEventType[]): Timerange[] =>
  R.pipe(
    R.filter<TimestampedEventType>(({ label }) => [EventLabel.started, EventLabel.answered].includes(label)),
    R.tap((filtered) => console.log(filtered, 'filtered')), // <=== this fixes the typing !?!?
    R.reduce<TimestampedEventType, TimerangeReduceResult>(
      ({ result, current }, next): TimerangeReduceResult => {
        if (next.label === EventLabel.started) {
          return {
            result,
            current: {
              start: next.timestamp,
            },
          };
        }
        if (next.label === EventLabel.answered && !!current.start) {
          return {
            result: [
              ...result,
              { start: current.start, end: next.timestamp, durationInMillis: next.timestamp - current.start },
            ],
          };
        }
        return { result };
      },
      { result: [] },
    ),
    R.prop('result'),
  )(events);
```

When I omit the line

```
R.tap((filtered) => console.log(filtered, 'filtered')), // <=== this fixes the typing
```

typescript is complaining about the following error

> Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Timerange[]':
> length, pop, push, concat, and 28 more.ts(2740) No overload matches
> this call.   The last overload gave the following error.
> Argument of type 'FilterOnceApplied' is not assignable to parameter of type '(x0: unknown, x1: unknown, x2:
> unknown) => readonly TimestampedEventType[]'.
> Type 'TimestampedEventType[] | Dictionary' is not assignable to type 'readonly TimestampedEventType[]'.
> Type 'Dictionary' is missing the following properties from type 'readonly TimestampedEventType[]':
> length, concat, join, slice, and 18 more.ts(2769)

Do anyone have a clue how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works fine with `ts@4.1.5`: [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEpwGZQiOAcimRABNlCBuAKBoFMAPSWOegOwFcCBRANw4wAMsgBG9ADZwA3jThxUMZLHpk4AXiKLlMVYQA0clO1QB3elFUaiyE%20ctkDRgMYALes4DWVzYTcfvR0MAXxoYAE8wejgAFVB6bXBVfkEYyOjNWXkJMUkALjgU9mFciVp5GHjEsAKuEHEoWmDaBmZoeGBii2xkZ2i4kAtbAHNorIUlWAB%20Wu4G8rZ2Mhm4OvmjMk4SSoh2AEl2AFlgCQlgVBW1iya6CKjY%20JJ2UYxVTj7X1E4JeEy4Sy%20PwKAyGz3oAG0ALpUOA5RQrEFPUZwZp0Zy7RRwc48YAwdxQADKk10ZAA8lAAIJ2Cw%20TAAOjAeDABOQlVQ2GACQAFDQAJAYOn0XH4rkC%20gAR04yAkqC5RRK4gkdO0KjIAEp9PSJVKZXKBMURIq6bYzDT1Rq%20YQcoqnGqWuiTPAHO8LNYBc6%20gAeEHVZL6mBpKKaxEjeivTYfBLfGAAPh5vK50n%20UZ%20mrh8GCmtx9BAao0MZkfOA2DgXOzIDp1skGnUmnlhskyuJqjzsl5vMsMC27EL7YB0cM7ecW0sxQKbfbKpgBXLdMqg2qg95mb5y9oy7ovOLpdnVaktbr-obSpN9isADJz7C0DApk2dK3V53u72Oynp3BwaveXTf-3U9%20SZTgU6b3rAmocGQM66BW84JEo4Caps2zALsBzHKc5zQTmc5VAhYBwAAtNeihgRmS6QkuqIbm%20XZQD2Sb-hmCyZryRiMe%20BRQiihh2nQTAsPADqYhySxEjoPBLAACsgwBQOgmgCmAwBRJ6Rg%20vhfqpOkUKaupeGkFEZDyoGEKUfpgxImGbyRoCMCGPIIZglCNBxkYAocj8FhlqgOJ4hY4mquSVKmg4FryB6FgOfSjIQGAXLEO%20hAWnaQA)

```js
import * as R from 'ramda';

export enum EventLabel {
  started = 'started',
  answered = 'answered',
  checked = 'checked',
}
type TimestampedEventType = {
  label: EventLabel;
  timestamp: number;
};

export interface Timerange {
  start?: number;
  end?: number;
  durationInMillis?: number;
}

type TimerangeReduceResult = { result: Timerange[]; last?: Timerange };

const isEitherStartedOrAnswered = R.propSatisfies(
    R.either(R.equals(EventLabel.started), R.equals(EventLabel.answered)),
    'label',
);

const reducer = R.reduce<TimestampedEventType, TimerangeReduceResult>(
    ({ result, last }, item) => {
    if (item.label === EventLabel.started) {
        return {
        result,
        current: {
          start: item.timestamp,
        },
      };
    }

    if (item.label === EventLabel.answered && last?.start) {
        return {
        result: [
          ...result,
          { start: last.start, end: item.timestamp, durationInMillis: item.timestamp - last.start },
        ],
      };
    }
    return { result };
  },    
  { result: [] },
);

export const findStartEndPairs = R.pipe<
  TimestampedEventType[], 
  TimestampedEventType[],
  TimerangeReduceResult,
  Timerange[]
>(
  R.filter(isEitherStartedOrAnswered),
  reducer,
  R.prop('result'),
);
```

Comment: Ah, thanks a lot. I missed the first type in `.pipe<...>`. When I add this also my version is working. But It is a little bit more work to type all steps in Pipe. The Type inference is not so reliable here :-( Or do I miss something to get it inferred?